# Conditional breakpoint when heap > some limit

Tags: visual-studio-2005, memory-leaks, debugging

Is it possible to break into debugger when the allocated memory of attached-to process becomes bigger than a certain value?

Preferrably using Visual Studio 2005, but other IDE's/debuggers are an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it. Alternative is to set ordinary breakpoint somewhere inside CRT allocation code, and set it to break when the hit count is multiple of say 2000. You'll get to wanted state quickly enough.

Comment: I saw slow brakpoints that track the change in memory (data breakpoints), but this is regular breakpoint that just continues execution 1999 times out of 2000. AFAIK it shouldn't be slow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any direct way in Visual Studio, but you could use [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) to create a crash dump when the Memory commit threshold reaches a certain value (-m option).

You would then need to use WinDbg (part of the [Windows debugging tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en)) to inspect the heap.